# Many to Many Polymorphic relationship alternative

Tags: postgresql, laravel, eloquent, polymorphic-associations

I'm designing a database schema for a huge application. I have different types of objects (buildings, lands, etc., total 9 of them) and all of them have 2 types of owners: person and company. Each object can have multiple owners of different types with different shares and each owner can have multiple types of property. Many to Many Polymorphic relationship should solve this, but how do I do this in a conventional way?

Answer (score 0):

You want an abstract type "Party", and concrete types "Individual" and "Organization" (which you can extend to Company or Government, say). And a table describing the ownership of an organization.

```
create table parties (
  party_id int primary key,
  type text not null check (...),
  individual_name text null,
  organization_name text null,

  check ( /* validate columns for given types */ )
);

create table shareholders (
  shareholder_party_id int references parties(party_id),
  organization_party_id int references parties(party_id),
  share decimal(...) not null,

  primary key (shareholder_party_id, organization_party_id),

  check (...)
);

insert into table parties values
(1, 'Individual', 'Alice', null),
(2, 'Individual', 'Bob', null)
(3, 'Organization', null, 'Alice and Bob Co.');

insert into shareholders values
(1, 3, 0.5), --Alice owns 50% of Alice and Bob Co.
(2, 3, 0.5); --Bob owns 50% of Alice and Bob Co.

insert into assets (asset_id, owner_id) values (1, 3); --Alice and Bob Co own Asset 1
```